# How to see my unpublished github applications?

Tags: github, github-api, vercel

When I set up a new integration for some remote tool, I go to the github "new application" URL.
https://github.com/settings/applications/new
This lets me create a new github application, and generate authtokens for that application.
I also get an application ID, what looks like a 64-bit hex code.

However, when I go to https://github.com/settings/applications or https://github.com/settings/installations I do not see this application.

I'm looking at the REST API documentation, but I also can't find a URL that lets me list this kind of unpublished application.

How do I get a list of my unpublished GitHub integrations/applications created like this?

(The problem I'm trying to solve is that I've deployed a template application on vercel, and it uses sign-in-with-github through nextjs, but the "redirect URL" is wrong, and I want to update the "redirect URL" that was set up for this unpublished app when I created it.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question, turns out to be that unpublished apps live in a totally different area of the settings.
The correct path is Settings -> Developer Settings -> apps
Or this URL: https://github.com/settings/developers

The first three times I tried to Google for the answer, I did not find any applicable answers, but patiently following multiple links on the github docs, finally got me to the right spot.